# 2 консоли в одном проекте C# .NET

Tags: c#, многопоточность, консоль

Хай, у меня есть проект в котором есть класс сервера и класс клиента.
Хотелось бы реализовать следующее:
При запуске проекта запускается первая консоль, в которой работает сервер(выводит кто подключился прочее), а в другой консоли собственно сам клиент.
То есть, как создать проект, в котором запускается две консоли которые работают отдельно?

Comment: никак - один проект, одна консоль.

Comment: @Grundy прям вот никак?

Comment: Можно запустить отдельный процесс, и туда писать из вашего процесса. Но зачем? Почему вам не сделать 2 проекта, один сервер, второй клиент?

Comment: @Zergatul можете скинуть пример кода

Comment: @GrandMax13 Зачем пример? В солюшне создаете еще один проект и делаете в нем клиент, а в первом сервер. В настройках солюшна можете сделать одновременный запуск обоих проектов для отладки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот пример. Все что вы введете в главном окне, отобразится во втором:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string pipeName = "MyAppPipe";

    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main window");

        var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Process.Start(process.MainModule.FileName, "client");

        var pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 4);
        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

        var writer = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);
        while (true)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
            writer.Flush();
            pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second window");

        var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None);
        if (pipeClient.IsConnected != true)
            pipeClient.Connect();

        var reader = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
        while (pipeClient.IsConnected)
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно ли запустить метод в отдельном процессе?

Comment: @GrandMax13 у вас 2 экземпляра одного приложения. Вы можете запустить во втором что угодно.

Comment: огромный респект за такой простой пример работы с *named pipes*

Answer (score 1):

В качестве дополнения к отличному ответу @Zergatul, давайте оформим этот код в класс, которым можно пользоваться отдельно. Моя цель — получить класс `AlternateConsole`, которым можно пользоваться при помощи `WriteLine` и тому подобных функций. Организуем код отдельным классом. Нам имеет смысл поддерживать интерфейс `IDisposable`.

```cs
class AlternateConsole : IDisposable
{
    readonly TextWriter writer;
    AlternateConsole(NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer) =>
        writer = new StreamWriter(pipeServer) { AutoFlush = true };

    public static AlternateConsole CreateServer(Action<string> startClientProcessCallback)
    {
        string pipeToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = null;
        try
        {
            pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeToken);
            startClientProcessCallback(pipeToken);
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            pipeServer?.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
        return new AlternateConsole(pipeServer);
    }

    public static void RunClient(string pipeToken)
    {
        using NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(pipeToken);
        pipeClient.Connect();
        using var sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient, leaveOpen: true);
        while (sr.ReadLine() is string s)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public void WriteLine(string s) => writer.WriteLine(s);
    public void WriteLine() => writer.WriteLine();
    public void Dispose() => writer.Dispose();
}
```

Коротко об изменениях.

- Я поменял фиксированное имя канала на генерируемый случайно `pipeToken`, чтобы разные экземпляры программы не конфликтовали между собой.
- Я добавил к `StreamWriter`'у `AutoFlush`, чтобы не нужно было вызывать `Flush` вручную каждый раз.
- Код запуска нового экземпляра я оставил главной программе, т. к. только она может решать, будет ли новый экземпляр в том же или в другом исполнимом файле, и как именно передавать аргументы командной строки. Для этого запуска у нас появилась callback-функция `startClientProcessCallback`.
- Сервер должен быть создан (при помощи `CreateServer`), и с ним должны работать (функция `WriteLine`), а потом уничтожить (`Dispose`).
- С клиентом всё проще, его код выполняется как есть, без пользовательских «вставок», поэтому для него достаточно статической функции `RunClient`.
- Дополнительных консолей можно легко заводить хоть сто штук.

Пишем вот такую программу, которая будет пользоваться альтернативной консолью:

```cs
class Program
{
    const string parameterForSecondProcess = "--secondary";

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.FirstOrDefault() == parameterForSecondProcess)
            return RunClient(args);
        else
            return RunServer(args);
    }

    static int RunServer(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using var altConsole = AlternateConsole.CreateServer(StartClientProcess);
            Console.Write("Enter a line: ");
            var l = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Output on second console");
            altConsole.WriteLine(l);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: second console disconnected: {ex.Message}");
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static void StartClientProcess(string pipeToken)
    {
        var path = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(path)
        {
            ArgumentList = { parameterForSecondProcess, pipeToken },
            UseShellExecute = true
        });
    }

    static int RunClient(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AlternateConsole.RunClient(args[1]);
        }
        catch
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Давайте посмотрим, как можно улучшить наш код. У нас пока нету функции `AlternateConsole.Write`. Её наивная реализация

```cs
public void Write(string s) => writer.WriteLine(s);
```

не работает: ведь клиент читает данные построчно, а мы не посылаем конец строки! Нам нужна семантика не потока, а отдельных сообщений. У named pipe есть режим сообщений: `PipeTransmissionMode.Message`, но он работает только на Windows. Поэтому сделаем так: пускай единицей обмена таки будет строка, но мы реальные символы перевода строки будем экранировать, а в конец добавлять фиктивный символ перевода строки, означающий конец сообщения.

При экранировании вместо перевода строки будем посылать `\n`, и чтобы всё хорошо работало, нам надо экранировать и бэкслэш тоже. В результате у нас в `AlternateConsole` появляются новые функции

```cs
static string Escape(string s) => s.Replace("\\", @"\\").Replace("\n", @"\n").Replace("\r", @"\r");
static string Unescape(string s) => s.Replace(@"\\", "\\").Replace(@"\n", "\n").Replace(@"\r", "\r");
```

Функции отправки перепишутся так:

```cs
public void Write(string s) => writer.WriteLine(Escape(s));
public void WriteLine(string s) => writer.WriteLine(Escape(s + '\n'));
public void WriteLine() => writer.WriteLine(Escape("\n"));
```

а рабочий цикл клиента будет теперь

```cs
while (sr.ReadLine() is string s)
    Console.Write(Unescape(s));
```

Теперь, чего нам ещё не хватает? У нас нет функции `ReadLine`, которяа позволяла бы вводить текст на альтернативной консоли! Для этого нам придётся немного реорганизовать код, теперь нам нужно два потока: `TextReader` и `TextWriter`.

Получаем следующие изменения в коде:

```cs
class AlternateConsole : IDisposable
{
    readonly NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer;
    readonly TextWriter writer;
    readonly TextReader reader;

    AlternateConsole(NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer)
    {
        this.pipeServer = pipeServer;
        writer = new StreamWriter(pipeServer, leaveOpen: true) { AutoFlush = true };
        reader = new StreamReader(pipeServer, leaveOpen: true);
    }
```

и

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    reader.Dispose();
    writer.Dispose();
    pipeServer.Dispose();
}
```

Теперь, как организовать запрос данных? Раз у нас уже целые сообщения, то можно в начало сообщения приписать *команду*, чтобы было понятно, что мы хотим от клиента. Пойдём простым путём: односимвольная команда, остальное — её аргумент(ы). Команду для записи назовём `W`, для чтения `R`. Получаем:

```cs
public void Write(string s) => writer.WriteLine(Escape('W' + s));
public void WriteLine(string s) => writer.WriteLine(Escape('W' + s + '\n'));
public void WriteLine() => writer.WriteLine(Escape("W\n"));
public string ReadLine()
{
    writer.WriteLine("R");
    return Unescape(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

На стороне клиента нам придётся теперь завести небольшой интерпретатор команд:

```cs
public static void RunClient(string pipeToken)
{
    using NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(pipeToken);
    pipeClient.Connect();
    using var sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient, leaveOpen: true);
    using var sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient, leaveOpen: true) { AutoFlush = true };
    while (sr.ReadLine() is string s)
    {
        var message = Unescape(s);
        if (message == "")
            throw new ProtocolViolationException("Message should start with a prefix");
        switch (message[0])
        {
            case 'W':
                Console.Write(message[1..]);
                break;
            case 'R':
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(Escape(input));
                break;
            default:
                throw new ProtocolViolationException("Unknown message prefix");
        }
    }
}
```

Раз уж мы ввели полновесную концепцию сообщений <s>и уверено двигаемся в сторону изобретения RPC</s>, давайте добавим ещё какой-нибудь сервис. Например, установим имя консоли:

```cs
public void SetTitle(string title) => writer.WriteLine(Escape('T' + title));
```

и в цикле интерпретации сообщений

```cs
case 'T':
    Console.Title = message[1..];
    break;
```

Теперь можно и потестировать.

```cs
using var altConsole = AlternateConsole4.CreateServer(StartClientProcess);
Console.Title = "Primary Console";
altConsole.SetTitle("Secondary Console");
Console.Write("Enter a line: ");
var l = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Output on second console");
altConsole.WriteLine(l);
Console.WriteLine("Now input line on second console");
altConsole.Write("Input line here: ");
l = altConsole.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine($"You entered: {l}");
```

Получаем вот что:

[image: красивая картинка]

---

Вот gist, чтобы не набирать код вручную: https://gist.github.com/vladd/710687e1916510345d6654e11eabea01